# Can a single trigonometric term be the solutions of a depressed cubic?

Tags: trigonometry, cubics

For example a term like $\cos\big(\frac{\pi}{7}\big)$ (where the argument is a rational multiple of $\pi$), not including terms like $\cos\big(\frac{\pi}{7}\big)+1$

Comment: How do you define depressed cubic?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for example $\,\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{9}\right)\,$ is a root of $\,8 x^3 - 6 x - 1\,$, per the triple angle cosine identity:

$$
\frac{1}{2} = \cos \left(3 \cdot \frac{\pi}{9}\right) = 4 \cos^3\left(\frac{\pi}{9}\right) - 3 \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{9}\right)
$$

Comment: Let's see, roots of $x^3 - 3x + 1$ are  $2 \cos \left( \frac{2\pi}{9} \right), \; \; $$2 \cos \left( \frac{4\pi}{9} \right), \; \; $$2 \cos \left( \frac{8\pi}{9} \right), \; \; $ where the third one gives your example...see middle of page 174 in https://books.google.com/books?id=wt7lgfeYqMQC&pg=PR1&lpg=PR1&dq=reuschle++tafeln+complexer+primzahlen&source=bl&ots=VGZFPrfUBn&sig=MlQ667PqXaQ9rAvLWkG3_F1rwsk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIwtSvm9TQAhUJ-2MKHXJIA_kQ6AEIODAE#v=onepage&q=reuschle%20%20tafeln%20complexer%20primzahlen&f=false

Comment: uses $\omega^9 - 1 = (\omega-1)(\omega^2 + \omega + 1)(\omega^6 + \omega^3 + 1)$   with $x = \omega + \frac{1}{\omega},$ meanwhile $\omega$ is any one of $e^{2 \pi i / 9} \; , \; $$e^{4 \pi i / 9} \; , \; $ $e^{8 \pi i / 9} \; . \; $